# .net pop3 over http proxy

Tags: .net, sockets, pop3

so, i got mailsystem.net from codeplex(http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/), to write pop3 client.
problem is, i want to use http proxy.
found some hints at:

[How to open socket thru proxy server in .Net C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127127/how-to-open-socket-thru-proxy-server-in-net-c/3127176#3127176)

and here is
my code:

```
Pop3Client pop = new Pop3Client();
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                             SocketType.Stream,
                             ProtocolType.Tcp);
sock.Connect("79.172.35.74", 82); // here is proxy
sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("CONNECT pop.yandex.ru:110 HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>")); // here pop3 server
sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<CR><LF>"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[25];
sock.Receive(buffer);
pop.Client = sock;
pop.Connect(config.pop3.host, config.pop3.username, config.pop3.password);
```

so, it fails at last line, with socket exception. what can i do? or any free pop3client libraries with proxy support?

Comment: P.S, `<CR><LF>`  in C# are represented as `"\r\n"`  `"\r" = <CR>` and `"\n"=<LF>`

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the post you link to:

> 1. Connect to proxy.
> 2. Issue `CONNECT Host:Port HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>`
> 3. Issue `<CR><LF>`
> 4. Wait for a line of response. If it contains `HTTP/1.X 200`, the connection is successful.
> 5. Read further lines of response until you receive an empty line.
> 6. Now, you are connected to the outside world through a proxy. Do any data exchange you want.

Where is it that you do bullet nr. 5? Where do you read all lines until you receive an empty line?

Other then that, I do not know what the problem might be. You could choose to use [Starksoft Proxy library](http://www.starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html) to help you.

Comment: P.S, `<CR><LF>`  in C# are represented as `"\r\n"`  `"\r" = <CR>` and `"\n"=<LF>`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
pop.Connect(config.pop3.host, config.pop3.username, config.pop3.password);
```

is not needed, your **socket is already connected**. You should only log in.

You may try [Mail.dll POP3 component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/). Please note that it's a commercial (not free) product that I've created.

It supports HTTP and SOCKS proxies:

http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/imap-pop3-smtp-via-http-socks-proxy/