# Connect to a TCP server via TcpClient through proxy

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

My system is accessing internet via a proxy server
(IE proxy server address : myserver.mydomain.com , port: 80).
Im trying to send some data to a TCP server using class `"System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient"`. But i am unable to connect. If I try using static IP internet, i am able to connect.
Is there any way to provide proxy address ? I am pretty sure the problem is the proxy, because i have tried from two systems which do not use proxy and it worked fine.
My application is a console application.

My Code is something like :

```
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("tcpserver.com", 3101);
            string message = "message";

            byte[] auditMessageStream;
            auditMessageStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            int i = tcpClient.Client.Send(auditMessageStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [opensource lib](http://www.starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html) to create a socket conection through a proxy.

Watch [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127127/how-to-open-socket-thru-proxy-server-in-net-c/3127176#3127176) too

Comment: I tried this opensource lib but apparently our proxy is blocking it too. ("bad request. code 400"). Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

You need HTTP tunneling unless your proxy is a SOCKS proxy.